# Collapsable divs (e.g. using fadeout()). What determines if content below moves up, or content above moves down to fill space?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok so I have a few collapsable divs using the fadeout() function. Like so:

```
var clicks = 1;
function clickme(x) {
    $(x).fadeOut();

    if(clicks == 4) {
        var pos = 4;
        var rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * pos) + 1);
       var button = ' <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onClick = \'document.getElementById("holder").style.display="block"\'>--></a>';
        $("#pos" + rand).html(button);
    }
    clicks++;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/00Lodcqf/130/

My question is how can I get the content above the collapsable divs to move down, rather than the content below moving up to replace the collapsed div area?

Thank you.

Comment: I didn't get your question?

Comment: You want to replace faded out element with something else or what??? Once element is faded out, the display is set to none, so it doesn't take anymore space on page. You could instead animate `opacity` to keep space BUT why would you expect other following element to move down?

Comment: I want the div to collapse down so that content above the div moves down to fill its place. Unlike in the jsfiddle where content moves up to fill the gap.